# Moq setup return different based on where method is called from

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a test where a method is being used in different methods. Based on which methods it's being called from it has to return either `true` or `false`.

```
private bool FirstTrue()
{
     return class.method();
}
```

```
private bool SecondFalse()
{
     return class.method();
}
```

How would I go about setting the mock of the class up to return either true or false based on where it is being called from?

I have tried setting it up as:

```
classMock.Setup(g => g.Method())
                .Returns(() =>
                {
                    if (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name == "FirstTrue")
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;         
                });
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this all in a single test? Can you guarantee the order of execution?

Comment: This is in a single test yes, the order is not set. It's using a large XML as reference where it's just too much work to find out the exact order or use SetupSequence.

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything you can do then. Perhaps check the parameters passed in to the method you are mocking so you return the correct value?

Comment: The parameters are large lists of coordinates, so testing for that each time is too much work also sadly.

Comment: You should think of a different test approach. A simple refactoring (e. g. rename) would make your tests red. You could describe your test problem and perhaps there's an idea on that.